# Get prev year record in SQL Server

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I need to get the prev year records along with current year

input

```
id      year    amount  
----------------------
1001    2012    3747    
1001    2012    3747    
1002    2013    5746    
1002    2013    5746    
1003    2014    6756    
1003    2014    6756    
1004    2015    8746
```

Desire output:

```
id      year    amount  prevAmount
----------------------------------
1001    2012    3747    null
1001    2012    3747    null
1002    2013    5746    3747
1002    2013    5746    3747
1003    2014    6756    5746
1003    2014    6756    5746
1004    2015    8746    6756
```

Comment: `SELECT *, LAG(net_sales,2) OVER (ORDER BY month) as PrevAmount from Table` Can you try this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You can use LAG function if you have same number of repetition of every years entry :-

Use following [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=505b91a294f9165b52e29e0400df9c6d)

**`Create Table:-`**

```
create table yourtable(id  int,    year numeric(10),    amount numeric(10));

insert into yourtable
select 1001 ,   2012 ,  3747 union all   
select 1001 ,   2012 ,  3747 union all   
select 1002 ,   2013 ,  5746 union all   
select 1002 ,   2013 ,  5746 union all   
select 1003 ,   2014 ,  6756 union all   
select 1003 ,   2014 ,  6756 union all   
select 1004 ,   2015 ,  8746;
```

**`Fetch Data:-`**

```
select *,LAG(amount,2) OVER(order by year) as PrevAmount from yourtable ;
```

### **For more information you can [use this link.](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/11/15/sql-server-introduction-to-lead-and-lag-analytic-functions-introduced-in-sql-server-2012/**)

### If you have random number of repetition of every years entry :-

**`Create Table:-`**

```
create table yourtable(id  int,    year numeric(10),    amount numeric(10));

insert into yourtable
select 1001 ,   2012 ,  3747 union all   
select 1001 ,   2012 ,  3747 union all   
select 1001 ,   2012 ,  3747 union all
select 1002 ,   2013 ,  5746 union all   
select 1002 ,   2013 ,  5746 union all   
select 1003 ,   2014 ,  6756 union all   
select 1003 ,   2014 ,  6756 union all   
select 1004 ,   2015 ,  8746 union all
select 1004 ,   2015 ,  8746;
```

**`Fetch Data:-`**

```
with cte as (
select dense_rank() over(order by year) as rn1,* from yourtable
),cte1 as(
select distinct rn1+1 as rn2,* from cte
)
select cte.id,cte.year,cte.amount,cte1.amount as PrevAmount  
from cte left join cte1 on cte.rn1=cte1.rn2
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use a `apply`:

```
select t.*, tprev.amount
from t outer apply
     (select top (1) tprev.*
      from t tprev
      where tprev.year = t.year - 1
     );
```

Normally, there would be an `order by` with `select top`, but it doesn't seem to make a difference for your data.

Comment: RANGE is only supported with UNBOUNDED and CURRENT ROW window frame delimiters. this is error i'm getting. i tries using Lag function but didn't help.

Comment: @Quikr . . . I fixed the answer.  I forget sometimes that `range between` is not standard in SQL Server.